# Find generating function for $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=n$ while that $x_1\ne x_2$ and $x_1\lt x_2$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

Find generating function for $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=n$ with the following constraints:

a) $x_1\ne x_2$

b) $x_1\lt x_2$

Can you please give me a direction or hint of how to represent in a generating function the fact that $x_1$ differs from $x_2$?

Comment: Well, interchanging $x_1,x_2$ shows that exactly half of the $4-$ tuples in which $x_1\neq x_2$ satisfy $x_1<x_2$.

Comment: Okay, but I want to find a closed form expression using generating function. How does that help me?

Comment: You asked for a hint, and I gave you one.  For another:  it's easy to get the unrestricted total.  If you can solve the $x_1=x_2$ case you can then just subtract.

Comment: @lulu Can you help me with the second case? I'm struggling to represent this in a generating function. Should I just divide the generating function of a) by 2?

Comment: Do you need the generating function to find the number of compositions? You can find the number of compositions in 3 steps. 1) calculate number of compositions for $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=n$ unrestricted, call it $M_1$. 2) calculate number of compositions for $2x_1+x_3+x_4=n$, unrestricted, call it $M_2$. 3) $M_1 -M_2$ will give you the number of compositions without $x_1 < x_2$ restriction, to sort this out, take $\frac{M_1 -M_2}{2}$ since half of $M_1 -M_2$ will be with $x_1<x_2$ and half with $x_1 > x_2$. Obviously, cases 1) and 2) will use much simpler generating functions.

Comment: Thank you. Can you write it as an answer so I could mark this thread as answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** if you try to find the number of compositions, satisfying the above criteria, you can do it in 3 steps.

1. Calculate number of compositions for $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=n$
   unrestricted, call it $M_1$.
2. Calculate number of compositions for $2x_1+x_3+x_4=n$,
   unrestricted, call it $M_2$.
3. $M_1 -M_2$ will give you the number of compositions without $x_1
   < x_2$ restriction. To sort this out, take $\frac{M_1 -M_2}{2}$
   since half of $M_1 -M_2$ will be with $x_1<x_2$ and half with $x_1 >
   x_2$.

Obviously, cases $1$ and $2$ will use much simpler generating functions.