# no of non negative solutions of equation a+b+c+...n variables=N where a<=b<=c<=d<=....

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions

I need to find the number of non negative solutions of equation 
$\underbrace{a+b+c+ \dotsb }_{n \text{ variables}}=N$ where $a\le b \le c \le d \le \dotsb $.

What I have tried is:

> Suppose $S(n)$ gives us the required solution.
>
> For $n=1$, only one solution $(a=N)$, $S(1)=1$
>
> for $n=2$, $a+b=N$. $a$ can take either $0$ or non zero.
>        if a takes 0 then total solutions = $S(1)=1$;
>        otherwise, a can take values from 1 to N/2 so total floor(N/2) possible solutions.
>        Hence $S(2)=S(1)+N/2 = 1 + N/2$
>
> for $n=3, a+b+c=N$, a can take either 0 or non zero
>        if a takes 0 then total solutions = $S(2)$
>        otherwise , a can take values from 1 to N/3 so total floor(N/3) possible solutions.
>        Hence $S(3)= S(2) + N/3 = 1 + N/2 + N/3$
>
> Similarly for $n=n$,
>        $S(n)=1+ N/2 + N/3 + N/4 + ....... + N/n$

Can anyone tell whether the above formula is right or wrong?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Why downvoted. I was even editing the question

Comment: This seems to be related (that $\le n$ looks weird) to "The number of weak compositions of $N$ into exactly $n$ parts"

Comment: The question was unclear until just now.

Comment: For $n=3,N=5$ you get $1+\lfloor \frac 52\rfloor +\lfloor \frac 53\rfloor=4$, no?  But we have $(0,0,5),(0,1,4),(0,2,3),(1,1,3),(1,2,2)$.

Comment: @lulu yes it is wrong

Comment: @mvw It means that I dont need to worry about constraint. I need to find only possible solution (without any repetition)  and count that?

Comment: Have you had a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics))?

Comment: @mvw Oh man, I was thinking for very long and didn't realized that it is the same thing as distributing n identical balls into k identical boxes. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Sounds reasonable, but I tend to make mistakes in combinatorics.

Comment: Here is an example https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2623657/number-of-positive-integral-solutions-of-abcde-20-such-that-abcde-an/2623713#2623713

Comment: And another one https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2862475/find-the-number-of-ways-to-choose-n-non-negative-numbers-that-sum-up-to-s-and

Comment: The terminology you need to find an answer is "partitions of N into at most n parts", although the most standard variable naming would be "partitions of n into at most k parts".