# $x+y+z=n$. Finding the number of solutions.

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

I have found two formulas. I want to connect them!

> The number of ways in which a given positive integer $n≥3$ can be expressed as a sum of three positive integers $x,y,z$ (i.e. $x+y+z=n$) , subject to $x≤y≤z$ is the integer closest to $\frac{n^2}{12}$.
>
> If $x+y+z=n$ where $x,y,z$ are postive integers then the number of ways is ${n-1 \choose 2}$ .

The difference between these two formula is the condition $x≤y≤z$. Can we connect these two ?? Please help me!

I mainly wants to know how one implies the other.

Comment: Hint: When $x\le y\le z$,  one must have $z\ge n/3$

Answer (score 8):

Just by looking at the [generating functions](https://math.illinoisstate.edu/day/courses/old/305/contentgeneratingfunctions.html), we can see a link (colors applied) ...

---

The number of solutions for $x+y+z=n, x\geq1, y\geq1, z\geq1$ is the coefficient of $x^n$ term of the 
$$(x+x^2+x^3+...+x^k+...)^3=\color{red}{\frac{x^3}{(1-x)^3}}$$
But because
$$\color{blue}{\frac{1}{(1-x)^3}=
\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)^{''}=
\frac{1}{2}\left(\sum\limits_{k=0}x^k\right)^{''}=
\sum\limits_{k=2}\frac{k(k-1)}{2}x^{k-2}}$$
we have
$$\frac{x^3}{(1-x)^3}=
\sum\limits_{k=2}\frac{k(k-1)}{2}x^{k+1}=
\sum\limits_{k=3}\frac{(k-1)(k-2)}{2}x^{k}$$
and the coefficient of $x^n$ is $\color{green}{\frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{2}=\binom{n-1}{2}}$.

---

The number of solutions for $x+y+z=n, 1\leq x \leq y\leq z$ (like in [this example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2623657/number-of-positive-integral-solutions-of-abcde-20-such-that-abcde-an)) can be found from the reformulated version
$$x=x_1, y=x+y_1=x_1+y_1, z=y+z_1=x_1+y_1+z_1 \Rightarrow \\
3x_1+2y_1+z_1=n \\
x_1\geq1, y_1\geq0, z_1\geq0$$
with the generating function
$$\left(x^3+x^{2\cdot 3}+...+x^{k\cdot 3}+...\right)\left(1+x^2+x^{2\cdot 2}+...+x^{k\cdot 2}+...\right)\left(1+x^2+...+x^k+...\right)=\\
\frac{x^3}{1-x^3}\cdot \frac{1}{1-x^2}\cdot \frac{1}{1-x}=
\color{red}{\frac{x^3}{(1-x)^3}}\cdot\frac{1}{1+x}\cdot\frac{1}{1+x+x^2}=\\
\frac{1}{6(1-x)^3}-\frac{1}{4(1-x)^2}-\frac{1}{72(1-x)}-\frac{1}{8(1+x)}+\frac{2+x}{9(1+x+x^2)}=\\
\color{blue}{\sum\limits_{k=2}\frac{k(k-1)}{12}x^{k-2}}-
\sum\limits_{k=1}\frac{k}{4}x^{k-1}-
\sum\limits_{k=0}\frac{x^{k}}{72}-\sum\limits_{k=0}\frac{(-1)^kx^k}{8}+
\frac{2+x}{9}\sum\limits_{k=0}U_k\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)x^k$$
where $U_k(x)$ are [Chebyshev polynomials of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials). The coefficient of $x^n, n\geq2$ is
$$\frac{n(n-1)}{12}-\frac{n}{4}-\frac{1}{72}-\frac{(-1)^k}{8}+\frac{2}{9}U_n\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)+\frac{1}{9}U_{n-1}\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)=\\
\frac{6n^2-24n-1-9(-1)^n}{72}+\frac{2\sin{\left((n+1)\theta\right)}+\sin{\left(n\theta\right)}}{9\sin{\theta}}$$
where $\cos{\theta}=-\frac{1}{2}$. This is asymptotically close to $\color{green}{\frac{n^2}{12}}$.

Comment: This is a great answer!

Comment: Thank you, @JJC94!