# Number of integer solutions combinatorics problem

Tags: combinatorics

what is the number of integer solutions to
$$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5=18$$ with $$x_1\ge1\;\;\;x_2\ge2\;\;\;x_3\ge3\;\;\;x_4\ge4\;\;\; x_5\ge5$$

I know I have to use this formula $$\frac{(n+r-1)!}{(n-1)!\;r!}= {{n+r-1}\choose r}$$

My instinct says that I should use $n=18-1-2-3-4=18-15=3$ and $r=5$ but I m not sure it makes sense?

Anyone can help me please?

Comment: You can use standard methods if you replace $x_i$ with $y_i=x_i-i$.  Then, since $1+2+3+4+5=15$ we just have $\sum y_i=3$ and $y_i≥0$.

Comment: Well ok but can you explain it a bit better? what is the standard method I should use and how does it help me get to a conclusion

Comment: The standard method goes by the name [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).  Though, really, it isn't that hard to count the number of $5$-tuples that add to $3$.

Comment: I am asking because I haven t studied this method and I m trying to figure it out on my own. Also it can be a bit difficult to count the number of 5-tuples if the number they have to add to is greater than 3 so I thought it would be useful to know the method in general. Thanks anyway ^^

Comment: The link I provided gives closed formulas (plus proofs) of the relevant formulas.

Answer (score 1):

We can simply give the required value to each pirate before counting. We don’t have any choice for them, so there is exactly one way to do this. Then, we distribute the remaining $18-5-4-3-2-1=3$ bars among the pirates.

This gives $$\dbinom{3+5-1}{3}=\dbinom{7}{3}$$

**Edit:**

Given $$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5=18$$and $$x_1\ge1\;\;\;x_2\ge2\;\;\;x_3\ge3\;\;\;x_4\ge4\;\;\; x_5\ge5$$
Let $$y_1 = x_1 − 1, y_2 = x_2 − 2, y_3 = x_3 − 3, y_4 = x_4 − 4, y_5 = x_5 − 5$$
$$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5=18$$$$(y_1 + 1) + (y_2 + 2) + (y_3 + 3) + (y_4 + 4) + (y_5 + 5) =18$$$$y_1 + y_2 + y_3 + y_4 + y_5 + y_6 = 3$$
There are $\dbinom{3+5-1}{3}=35$ solutions

Comment: What do you mean by pirate?

Comment: @voldetort It is like dividing the gold bars among pirates

Comment: That doesn t really explain anything. Can you explain the whole idea and method to someone who has no idea what you re talking about?

Answer (score 1):

We can change the problem from its original form
$$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5=18$$
$$x_1\ge1,x_2\ge2,x_3\ge3,x_4\ge4,x_5\ge5$$
to
$$y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4+y_5=(x_1-1)+(x_2-2)+(x_3-3)+(x_4-4)+(x_5-5)=3$$
$$y_1\ge0,y_2\ge0,y_3\ge0,y_4\ge0,y_5\ge0$$
and use [generating functions](https://math.illinoisstate.edu/day/courses/old/305/contentgeneratingfunctions.html) approach, giving the following function
$$(1+y+y^2+...+y^k+...)^5$$
and the coefficient of $y^3$ term is the answer, [which is](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=series%20expansion%20(1%2F(1-y))%5E5) 35. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2887540/finding-the-number-of-non-negative-integral-solutions-of-x-y-z-10/2887560#2887560) is another example to look at (which contains another link to another example ...).