# Number of integer solutions of the equation $x + y + z = 30$ if $x \geq 2$, $y \geq 0$, $z \geq -3$

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I am trying to solve a problem using permutation/combination but cannot figure out how to proceed.

> Suppose the sum of three variables $x, y, z$ is $30$. If $x\ge2, y\ge0, z\ge-3$, how many integer solutions exist?

I understand that $2\le x\le33, 0\le y\le31, -3\le z\le28$. A simple simulation shows that there are $528$ solutions. However, I am unable to calculate this mathematically. I would like a hint so that I can try this on my own.

Comment: There is a way to count solutions to $x+y+z=n$, where $x,y,z$ are the variables and $n$ is constant, and you are given $x,y,z\ge 0$, using stars and bars. See if you can transform your question into this one.

Comment: I just made the 1k th profile view of your account!

Answer (score 3):

From
$$x+y+z=30 \Rightarrow (x-2)+y+(z+3)=31 \Rightarrow x_1+y+z_1=31\\
x_1\geq0,y\geq0,z_1\geq0$$
[which has](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2877158/xyz-n-finding-the-number-of-solutions/2879198#2879198) $\binom{33}{2}=528$ integer solutions.

With more details, this is the generating function:

$$(1+x+x^2+...+x^k+...)^3=\frac{1}{(1-x)^3}=
\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)^{''}=\\
\frac{1}{2}\left(\sum\limits_{k=0}x^k\right)^{''}=
\sum\limits_{k=2}\frac{k(k-1)}{2}x^{k-2}$$
and the coefficient of $x^{31}$ is the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Set $a=x-2$, $b=y$ and $c=z+3$.

The problem is the same as finding the number of sums $a+b+c=31$ where $a,b,c$ are nonnegative integers.

Now apply [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).

Answer (score 2):

I started by fixing x=2, and counting all the solutions in y and z. For x = 2, we need $y+z=28$. Now, fixing y determines z. For y=0, z=28; y=1, z=27; ...; y=31, z = -3. So, we can count 32 solutions when x=2.

Then, I fixed x=3 and counted all the solutions in y and z again. A pattern emerges quickly.

Another hint:

> $\sum_{i=0}^{32}$ i = 528$

Comment: So as we increase the value of $x$ by $1$, the number of solutions for that value of $x$ decreases by $1$ as well until we are left with $x = 33, y = 0, z = -3$. Therefore, the total number of solutions is essentially $32 + 31 + 30 + \cdots + 1$.

Answer (score 2):

We wish to find the number of solutions of the equation
$$x + y + z = 30 \tag{1}$$
in the integers subject to the restrictions that $x \geq 2$, $y \geq 0$, and $z \geq -3$.

Let $x' = x - 2$, $y' = y$, and $z' = z + 3$.  Then $x', y', z'$ are nonnegative integers.  Substituting $x' + 2$ for $x$, $y'$ for $y$, and $z' - 3$ for $z$ in equation 1 yields
\begin{align*}
x' - 2 + y' + z' + 3 & = 30\\
x' + y' + z' & = 31 \tag{2}
\end{align*}
Equation 2 is an equation in the nonnegative integers.  A particular solution of equation 2 corresponds to the placement of two addition signs in a row of $31$ ones.  For instance, 
$$1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 + 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 +$$
corresponds to the solution $x_1 = 21$, $x_2 = 10$, $x_3 = 0$, while 
$$1 1 1 1 1 1 1 + 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 + 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1$$
corresponds to the solution $x_1 = 7$, $x_2 = 11$, $x_3 = 13$.  The number of solutions of equation 2 is the number of ways we can place two addition signs in a row of $31$ ones, which is equal to the number of ways we can select which $2$ of the $33$ positions required for $31$ ones and $2$ addition signs will be filled with addition signs.

> $$\binom{31 + 2}{2} = \binom{33}{2} = \frac{33!}{2!31!} = \frac{33 \cdot 32 \cdot 31!}{2 \cdot 1 \cdot 31!} = \frac{33 \cdot 32}{2} = 33 \cdot 16 = 528$$