# The number of solutions to $x_1+x_2+x_3\leq 11$, where $x_i\in\mathbb{Z}^+$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, inequality

> What is the number of solutions for the inequality
>   $$x_1+x_2+x_3 \leq 11$$
>   where $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$ are integers greater than $0$?
>
> Answer options: 182, 364 (correct), 78, 440

[original problem image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmObO.jpg)

---

I tried doing this using combination method

Since $x_1, x_2, x_3$ are integers greater than $0$, therefore value of $x_1 + x_2 + x_3$ satisfies $3 \leq x_1+x_2+x_3 \leq 11$.

> $$_2C_2 \;+\; _3C_2 \;+\; _4C_2 \;+\; \cdots \;+\; _{10}C_2$$

And my answer was $165$ but that is not correct. I am not able to figure out where I am making a mistake

Comment: You are right to subtract $3$ from $x_1, x_2, x_3$ so that they are all non-negative integers. Then the problem becomes a straightforward application of [stars and bars](https://brilliant.org/wiki/integer-equations-star-and-bars/). I suggest you to read up on this topic if you haven't learnt about it.

Comment: Please type up your question using MathJax instead of posting an image/screenshot.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 3):

Your answer is correct for the stated problem.  The given answer would be correct if $x_1, x_2, x_3$ were required to be nonnegative integers.

Here is another approach.

Since $x_1, x_2, x_3$ are positive integers, $x_1' = x_1 - 1$, $x_2' = x_2 - 1$, and $x_3' = x_3 - 1$ are nonnegative integers.  Substituting $x_1' + 1$ for $x_1$, $x_2' + 1$ for $x_2$, and $x_3' + 1$ for $x_3$ in the inequality
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 \leq 11 \tag{1}$$
yields
\begin{align*}
x_1' + 1 + x_2' + 1 + x_3 + 1 \leq 11\\
x_1' + x_2' + x_3' \leq 8
\end{align*}
Let the slack variable $s = 8 - (x_1' + x_2' + x_3')$.  Then $s$ is also a nonnegative integer.  Moreover,
$$x_1' + x_2' + x_3' + s = 8 \tag{2}$$
Thus, the number of solutions of inequality 1 in the positive integers is equal to the number of solutions of equation 2 in the nonnegative integers.  A particular solution of equation 2 in the nonnegative integers corresponds to the placement of $4 - 1 = 3$ addition signs in a row of eight ones.  For instance,
$$1 1 + + 1 1 1 1 + 1 1$$
corresponds to the solution $x_1' = 2$, $x_2' = 0$, $x_3' = 4$, $s = 2$ ($x_1 = 3$, $x_2 = 1$, $x_3 = 5$).  The number of such solutions is the number of ways we can place three addition signs in a row of eight ones, which is 
$$\binom{8 + 4 - 1}{4 - 1} = \binom{11}{3} = 165$$
since we must choose which three of the eleven positions required for eight ones and three addition signs will be filled with addition signs.

Your answer
$$\sum_{j = 2}^{10} \binom{j}{2} = \binom{11}{3}$$
by the [hockey-stick identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity), which states that 
$$\sum_{j = k}^{n} \binom{j}{k} = \binom{n + 1}{k + 1}$$
To see why it holds, we count $(k + 1)$-element subsets of the $(n + 1)$-element set $S = \{0, 1, 2, \ldots, n\}$ in two different ways.  There are 
$$\binom{n + 1}{k + 1}$$
such subsets.

The number of such subsets with largest element $j$ is 
$$\binom{j}{k}$$
since each such subset must contain exactly $k$ of the $j$ elements in $S$ smaller than $j$. Since the $(k + 1)$-element subset of $S$ contains $k$ of the $j$ elements of $S$ less than $j$, $k \leq j \leq n$.  Hence, the number of such subsets is 
$$\sum_{j = 0}^{n} \binom{j}{k}$$

Since we have counted the same $(k + 1)$-element subsets of the $(n + 1)$-element set $S$ in two different ways, the hockey-stick identity follows.

**How was the stated answer obtained?**

Finally, note that the stated answer of $364$ would be correct if the problem required $x_1, x_2, x_3$ to be greater than *or equal to* zero, in which case we would be solving the inequality in the nonnegative integers.  If we let 
$$s = 11 - (x_1 + x_2 + x_3)$$
then the number of solutions of inequality 1 in the nonnegative integers is equal to the number of solutions of the equation
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + s = 11 \tag{3}$$
in the nonnegative integers.  Equation 3 has 
$$\binom{11 + 4 - 1}{4 - 1} = \binom{14}{3} = 364$$
solutions in the nonnegative integers.

Answer (score 2):

Using the method of **generating functions** (for more details, please see [this asnwer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2877158/xyz-n-finding-the-number-of-solutions/2879198#2879198) and [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2909070/number-of-integer-solutions-of-the-equation-x-y-z-30-if-x-geq-2-y?noredirect=1&lq=1), I hope both are pretty detailed).

---

The number of solutions for $x+y+z=n, x\geq1, y\geq1, z\geq1$ is the coefficient of $x^n$ term of the 
$$(x+x^2+x^3+...+x^k+...)^3=\color{red}{\frac{x^3}{(1-x)^3}}$$
which is
$\color{green}{\frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{2}=\binom{n-1}{2}}$.
The final answer is $$\sum\limits_{n=3}^{11}\binom{n-1}{2}=165$$

because for $n \in \{1,2\}$ we have $\frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{2}=0$. So, **you are right**.

---

The number of solutions for $x+y+z=n, x\geq0, y\geq0, z\geq0$ is the coefficient of $x^n$ term of the 
$$(1+x+x^2+...+x^k+...)^3=\color{red}{\frac{1}{(1-x)^3}}$$
which is
$\color{green}{\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2}=\binom{n+2}{2}}$.
The final answer is $$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{11}\binom{n+2}{2}=364$$

---

Now, that you have two different answers with nearly different methods and looking at the image you posted, you can use this thread to complain.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the shortest proof of the fact that we can choose $3$ positive integers summing to $\le 11$ in $\binom{11}{3}$ ways is that choosing the $x_i>0$ is equivalent to choosing distinct values from $1$ to $11$ of $\sum_{i=1}^jx_i$ for $1\le j\le 3$. For example, $x_1=2,\,x_2=3,\,x_3=2$ is equivalent to partial sums $2,\,5,\,7$. The case with non-negative integers can be incremented to replace the maximum of $11$ with $14$.