# How to find a number of solutions for $x_1+x_2+\ldots+x_n=r$ where $r$ is divisible by 3 and for a given $l$ and $r$ such that $l\leq x_i \leq r$?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

> How to find a number of solutions for $x_1+x_2+\ldots+x_n=r$ where $r$ is divisible by 3 and for a given $l$ and $r$ such that $l\leq x_i \leq r$?

Comment: what is this have to do with Taylor expansion?

Comment: Letting $y_i=x_i-l$ this becomes a routine [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) problem.  $r$ can be whatever you want...divisibility by $3$ doesn't change the computation.

Comment: Or maybe using generating functions, similar to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2877158/xyz-n-finding-the-number-of-solutions/).