# How many pairs of $(x,y,z)$ for $x+y+2z=n$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> How many pairs of $(x,y,z)$ for $x+y+2z=n$ when $n$ is an odd integer $\geq 5$

For $n=5$ there are 2 pairs. $n=7$ there are 6 pairs. $n=9$ there are 12 pairs. $n=11$ there are 20 pairs.

$an^2 + bn + c = f(n)$

$25a + 5b + c = 2$

$49a + 7b + c = 6$

$81a + 8b + c = 12$

$f(n) = (n^2)/4 - n + 3/4 = (n-3)(n-1)/4$

Is there a better way to solve it?

Comment: Use generating functions, like [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2877158/xyz-n-finding-the-number-of-solutions/).

Answer (score 2):

put z=2 then x+y=n-2 has n-3 ways (x can be anything from 1 to n-3).

then put z=4 then x+y=n-4 has n-5 ways (x can be anything from 1 to n-5).

.

.

.

.

put z =n-3  then x+y =3 have 2 ways.

total number of cases = 2+4+ 6.......n-3 = 2(1+2+3....$\frac{n-3}{2}$) = 2 $\frac{(\frac{n-3}{2})(\frac{n-1}{2})}{2}$ = $\frac{(n-3)(n-1)}{4}$

---

Answer (score 1):

For $x,y,z\in \mathbb{N}, x,y,z\geq 0$,

When $n$ is odd, the number is:
$$ (n+1)+(n-1)+(n-3)+...+2=\frac{(n+1)(n+3)}{4} $$

when $n$ is even, the number is:
$$ (n+1)+(n-1)+(n-3)+...+1=(\frac{n+2}{2})^2 $$

Comment: Your answer for $n$ odd doesn't match aryan's or the OP's [I assume you mean the square of $(n+2)/2).$]

Comment: @coffeemath  Is it true now?

Comment: I think aryan assumes $x,y,z \ge 1$ and yours assumes $x,y,z \ge 0.$